# Migrate HAR hibernate archive to JBoss 7

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss

I'm migrating an application packaged as a HAR hibernate archive from JBoss AS5 to AS7.  I have a number of questions, and I know I have a number of hurdles I have to face in order to migrate my application successfully.  I don't mind researching things on my own - but at this point I'm not quite sure what is possible, or the direction I should take and would appreciate any pointers or comments.

I know that JBoss AS7 does not support HAR hibernate archives - so I have to make some sort of changes in order to get this to work.  My app requires hibernate3, which I include as a dependency.  My HAR is structured like

```
HAR
|
|-com
|  |-business classes
|     |-*class files and *hbm.xml files
|
|-META-INF
   |-hibernate.xml
```

My hibernate.xml file looks like

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:jboss:hibernate-deployer:1.0">

   <session-factory name="java:/hibernate/SessionFactory" bean="jboss.har:service=Hibernate">
      <property name="datasourceName">java:/MySqlDS</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

 <!-- <property name="sessionFactoryInterceptor">org.jboss.test.hibernate.SimpleInterceptor</property> -->
 <!-- <property name="hbm2ddlAuto">create</property> -->
      <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
      <depends>jboss:service=TransactionManager</depends>
   </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

We are using *hbm.xml files in our HAR to define entities, and not the newer style of hibernate annotations.  A couple of questions I have are:

-is there a way I can just package my HAR as a JAR and use it inside of AS7 without having to go through the trouble of rewrite my business classes to use annotations to define entities instead of using *hbm.xml files?
-if not is there a guide somewhere about converting your code to use hibernate annotations and persistence.xml?  I don't mind doing research but right now I'm not sure what I should be researching.

Comment: > I know that JBoss AS7 does not support HAR hibernate archives Could I ask you where do you know that from ?

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? I am encountering the same issue right now

Answer (score 1):

HAR archives do not exist in JBoss 7 anymore. In fact even the ServiceMBeanSupport does not exist anymore. One possibility is to use some mechanism to create the SessionFactory and inject it into the JNDI. Another possibility is to “use and not use” the new JPA api. By “use” I mean define Hibernate configuration in a persistence.xml file and use the mapping detection feature available. This would allow the plain renaming of the .har to a .jar with an added META-INF/persistence.xml file without the need to hardcode all the mappings and classes in a long list somewhere. By “not use” I mean to have the JPA initialized but use the old SessionFactory instead because there is no reason to change to the new API when the old one works quite well.
However, another problem is that JBoss 7 is bundled with Hibernate 4 and the migration might not be straightforward. However there is still a possibility to bundle a Hibernate as lower as 3.5 in your application. Here is the persistence.xml:

```html
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="X">
    <description>X</description>
    <jta-data-source>java:/XOracleDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
     <!-- This tells JBoss to use Hibernate 3 (as low as 3.5) bundled into the application  -->
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="hibernate3-bundled" />
        <!--<property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"/>-->
        <!-- This will bind the session factory to JNDI as we require -->
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="java:/hibernate/XOracleSessionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <!-- This is one of the trickiest parts as Hibernate 3.5 does not has a RegionFactory and we must use the one from ehcache to bridge the gap -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <!-- very important to allow same names as in JBoss 4 -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
        <!-- This will make use of JBoss managed transactions. The factory is already present in JNDI -->
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```